# How to do a break line between (Character/Numeric) and (Character/Numeric) types in R

Tags: r, paste, line-breaks

I have an easy question related to break lines in R.

I am trying to paste and I have problems to obtain break lines between the (Characters/Numeric).Remark that the values are contained in vectors (`V1=81,V2=55,V3=25`) I have tried this code:

```
cat(paste("Student Id:",V1,"Number of circuts:",V2,"Time (Minutes):",V3,sep='\n'))
```

But I obtain the values under the characters like this:

```
Student Id:
81
Number of circuts:
55
Time (Minutes):
25
```

Any idea to obtain the break line after the value of the vectors, the expected result would be like this:

```
Student Id: 81
Number of circuts: 55
Time (Minutes): 25
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to put the breakline `\n` manually and set `sep=""`, e.g.

```
cat(paste("Student Id:",V1,"\nNumber of circuts:",V2,"\nTime (Minutes):",V3,"\n", sep=''))

#Student Id:81
#Number of circuts:55
#Time (Minutes):25
```

**Edit**

Quick remark. Your attempt was missing the fact that the separator `sep` is placed between each two arguments of the `paste` function.

According to this, the breakline appears after both the names (e.g. `Student Id`) and the values (e.g. `81`). That's how you got your output.

Comment: You might want to explain why the OP's original attempt went wrong, for his future benefit.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like `sprintf` for these types of things.

Line breaks can be inferred from what is provided:

```
V1 = 81; V2 = 55; V3 = 25

cat(sprintf(
"Student Id: %s
Number of circuts: %s
Time (Minutes): %s", V1, V2, V3))
```

or can be done manually:

```
cat(sprintf("Student Id: %s\nNumber of circuts: %s\nTime (Minutes): %s", V1, V2, V3))
```

Both of the above would result in:

```
Student Id: 81
Number of circuts: 55
Time (Minutes): 25
```